# jQuery Animating Margin Of Div on page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a navigation bar at the moment using bootstrap and adding a jQuery effect on the brand area of the nav.

What I am trying to achieve: 
When the user scrolls, the text "company name" slides up and is replaced by the brand image. When the page is scrolled back to the top, the effect is reversed.
Here is my attempt so far:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
 if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
     $('.navbar').css({'background': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)'});
     $('.brand-content').animate({'marginTop' : "-=100px", function(){
        $('.navbar-brand').css({'font-size':'14px'});
        $('.brand-content').html('<img src="http://s12.postimg.org/hyoq90vkp/cpcm_logo.png"/>').animate({'marginTop' : "+=100px"});

}});


} else {
     $('.navbar').css({'background': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.15)'});
     $('.brand-content').animate({'marginTop' : "-=100px", function(){
          $('.navbar-brand').css({'font-size':'14px'});
          $('.brand-content').html('Company Name').animate({'marginTop' : "+=100px"});

}});

}
});
```

At the moment, the text slides up but the image does not slide down. I also noticed when I was working on this using fadeIn and fadeOut that the function was running each time the user scrolled rather than only running when they scroll from the top and when they return to the top.

I am open to trying any solution, as long as the effect is smooth.

Edit: https://jsfiddle.net/w8mm5mfc/1/ forgot to add the fiddle!

Comment: give me a sec, I am cleaning up some stuff on jsfiddle, uno momento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options, but I believe personally you are doing too much using javascript (much of the desired effect can be achieved with pure CSS).

I have updated your example: https://jsfiddle.net/74pwvw7a/2/

I have simplified your javascript to only keep track of whether or not your body of the page is being scrolled or not:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $("body").addClass('scrolling');
    } else {
        $("body").removeClass('scrolling');
    }
});
```

For the HTML, I added the image to always be part of the markup (but only showing the correct bit).

```
<div class="navbar-header"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
  <div class="brand-content">Company Name</div>
  <div class="brand-image">
      <img src="http://s12.postimg.org/hyoq90vkp/cpcm_logo.png"/>
  </div>
</a>
```

And the CSS changes:

```
.brand-content, .brand-image{
    display: block;
    background: green;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    transition : all 0.4s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
}

.brand-image img{
    height: 100%;
}

.navbar-brand{
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.scrolling .brand-image {
    display: block;    
}

.scrolling .brand-content {
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

What is happening?
- You are essentially only tweaking the margin for the text block. Once the page starts to scroll, you will give it a negative top margin and because the container has overflow: hidden, once it scrolls out of the view-port of the container it will be hidden. Because the image was underneath that element (and being cut out of view), it will conversely scroll into view. All animation are handled by css. You can tweak the easing and timing using the -transition property.

Answer (score 2):

Your jQuery is running every time because your function is firing every time the user scrolls, as defined on your first line:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
```

If you want to stop this from happening, you'll want to add a variable to track once it has happened for the first time, and then stop the function from running again if this variable has been set

For your second issue, you have a syntax error in your script:

```
$('.brand-content').animate({'marginTop' : "-=100px"}, function(){
    $('.navbar-brand').css({'font-size':'14px'});   ^
    $('.brand-content').html('<img src="http://s12.postimg.org/hyoq90vkp/cpcm_logo.png"/>').animate({'marginTop' : "+=100px"});
});
```

Notice the first line (where I have added the arrow) and last line - I have moved the curly brace close ("}") to after the marginTop statement, and removed it from the last line. It's subtle, but important!